# How to Bundle multiple ScriptBundle in to a new ScriptBundle

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, bundling-and-minification

This is what I did so far

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WebformsJS").Include(
      "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js",
      "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js",
      "~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js",
      "~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js",
      "~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js",
      "~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js",
      "~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js",
      "~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MsAjaxJS").Include(
    "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
    "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxApplicationServices.js",
    "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js",
    "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js"));


bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MegaJS").
    .Include("~/bundles/WebformsJS")
    .Include("~/bundles/MsAjaxJS"));
```

Then I render the MegaBundle in Site.Master file like this:

```
 <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MegaJS") %>
```

The application run with no errors, but when I View Page source I can see the include

```
<script src="/bundles/MegaJS?v="></script>
```

If you notice the version is blank and when I click the bundle script its empty

> My questions are:
>   1) Does creating bundle from other bundle's is supported 
>   2) If Yes! then is their an example I can follow.

Comment: The question is, why you want to combine the two bundles? We have the situation, that on some pages we only need the WebForms bundle and on others we need both. But it then makes sense to have them separted, cause likely the client already has the webforms bundle. At least in our case.

Comment: @Remy I have upgraded legacy site to 4.5 that uses its own bundling logic and it has the feature to make bundle from bundles. So in order to reduce less work modifying legacy code I would like to know if the feature is supported.

Answer (score 1):

No, currently you cannot include bundles within bundles, you can only include real assets.  This is something we have on our todo list for asset management though.  You can upvote this if this is a feature you desire [here](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/26).